# How to think about SATB when analysing piece on piano?

Tags: beginner, satb

I'm beginner, so I read music theory and didn't find straight clear answer about applying SATB in pieces (in modern particularly). What information could I get from dividing voices, seeing all this up and down stems and all this stuff. Or should it somehow help to read music? I'm really confused.

Comment: We need a clarification: **SATB** stands for "**S**oprano, **A**lto, **T**enor, **B**ass". It is a particular *texture* for vocal music, with four distinct vocal parts in conventionally-defined ranges. It is *not*, however, an analysis tool, so when you say you want to *apply SATB in pieces*, what do you intend to do? Are you creating a piano piece and want to know how the ideas of writing for SATB voices apply to piano music? Are you looking to take an existing piano piece and rewrite (arrange) it in the style of four-part vocal harmony?

Comment: @Aaron While that is a nominally helpful edit, I hesitate to reopen this until I see some indication that OP did in fact *intend* to ask about thinking about multiple voices during analysis of piano pieces. I've rolled back that edit, so if OP (Suslove) agrees with that edit's content, then they can simply **rollback to Aaron's revision** (and I will then be confident enough to cast my vote to reopen).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but SATB will only be found in pieces with four part harmony. Many piano pieces don't do that.

To help your reading, and understanding SATB, it's good to split the four up, and simply play each line separately. The S will usually be the melody, but the others will have continuity (they could be sung, and no-one wants to sing unsingable lines!), so will have some melodic nature of their own.

You could also examine each chord, to work out what it is, compared with I, and decide what intervals there are between notes, or work out what inversion of the chord is written.

Also, to help sight-reading, you could isolate and play, say, S and B together. That's surely easier than all four parts together.

Comment: Besides lines that get out of the range of my/your voice, what *is* an unsingable line? Maybe it's all that more modern music I've listened to (video game music, heavy metal, musicals, even Romantic-era music, etc.), but I've sung everything from tritones to songs with >3-octave ranges to heavy syncopation to mixed meter to quick vibrato and tremolo to leaps of a 10th or more, including from others' music by ear.

Comment: @Dekkadeci - you're very lucky/gifted/etc! I really meant 'unmelodic', rather than unsingable. Some of the middle lines can be that due to adhering to (or not) all the 'rules'. Lines that I (and poss. you) would think 'why bother?'.

Comment: @Dekkadeci can you sing (for example) the right hand part of Bach's C-sharp major prelude from WTC book one, BWV 848 (https://youtu.be/Z-c8WG2GTaI)?  That's the sort of thing I think of when I hear "unsingable lines."

Comment: @phoog - That was a pretty easy sight-read and sight-sing, actually.

Comment: @Dekkadeci at what tempo?

Comment: @phoog - Around 7 16th notes = 60 bpm (so faster than dotted quarter = 60 bpm) - around the speed of or a little slower than recordings I've heard (and then forgotten all but the beginning) of that Bach prelude.

Answer (score 0):

**SATB** (aka **S**oprano **A**lto **T**enor **B**ass) is not used as much for modern popular music like Pop or Rap, however it is still widely used with modern Classical and Romantic composers.
**SATB** is often used in church music and occasionally seen in film music; choral symphonies are relatively recent, being around for not quite 100 years yet. As a commenter said (user45266), the use of choir **SATB** is a textural technique used to give vocal depth to music so you you can't quite *apply* voices, it's like using another instrument.
However, the notation for an **SATB** choir is relatively simple, there are two ways to notate a such choir, one is more compact than the other for ease of use:

[image: Compact notation]

In the compact notation, you can see how the stems should be arranged. Sopranos and Tenors, stem up; Altos and Basses, stem down.

[image: Extended notation]

In the extended notation, you can see the approximate range for each voice. In the Tenors, the treble clef with the 8 connected to it means you read it as treble clef but you sing/play it an octave lower.

I'd advise looking at a few fugues, fugues are piano pieces written for 4 part harmony (like **SATB**). "The Well-Tempered Clavier" by Bach is a good place to start looking at 4-part harmony notation, fugues are written in the compact form given they're written for piano, see if you can pick out each part and gain experience from said notation.

Comment: These ranges aren't particularly accurate.  Range in fact depends on the skill of the singers, but there is no skill level at which basses are not asked to sing above G3: pieces with bass parts remaining below that pitch are uncommon.  Many amateur tenors will be unable reach C5 effectively.  Amateur adult altos also routinely sing above C5.